# I am trying to remove the background from the image in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

[image: a meteor]

I am trying to remove the background from the image in PS. I am new to PS and have tried the Color range option as follows with no luck

1. From the menu Select/Color Range
2. Click on the background area which will select some of the gray area
3. Adjust the Fuzziness and Range as shown below
4. Click on the eyedropper with a plus (+) next to it
5. Click on the gray areas that are not selected until you have a good coverage
6. Click OK
7. Press Ctrl-J to create a new layer with the selection

Any help would be great

Comment: I would probably go with Magnetic lasso with this one. Otherwise I might go with layer Masks, but the quality of at least the example image is not super good quality and there's that strong shadow. Magnetic lasso tool should work pretty fine with `Select > Refine edge`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this one as it is very basic and there are [many other possible duplicates](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphotoshop%5D+remove+background)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Photoshop expert but I've never listed to the method you are using. The image you're using is not very high quality, but for something as simple as that you should use the Polygon Lasso Tool (displayed below). You select all of the shape, once you're done copy and paste it in a new layer and erase the layer with the background.

[image]

To help you out I did it really quick. Maybe you'll need to erase some little white borders with the erase tool, but that's all.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As it is already said in the previous answers, the picture is of low quality and only using one of the Lasso tools will give you the best results than anyother method.

I'd probably use Poly Lasso Tool

Comment: This doesn't really provide any information that hasn't already been stated.  Please either make an edit with more detail or your answer may be removed.